# If I need to work before or after call virtual function, is NVI idiom always better than other interface?

Tags: c++, interface, derived-class, base-class

From what I understand, NVI idiom grants hardened privileges to base class and places constraints on derived classes.
Because behaviors such as pre-action, post-action, when to call are implemented in base class, and all derived classes are enforced and cannot change.
In other words, an interface that is difficult for users (creators of derived classes) to misuse.

So this interface looks useful for any base class that can be derived and need to work before or after call virtual function.

I've looked for downsides to applying this idiom, but it just seems more useful.

1. Some docs say that misuse of this idiom will make your code bigger, but I don't understand. Wouldn't it rather help reduce duplicate code?
2. If a derived class needs to call a virtual function of the base class, it can change the virtual function of the base class to `protected`.
3. Perhaps this idiom prevents the derived class from implementing special behavior (because it imposes constraints on the derived class). But I'm not sure if there can be any special behavior that makes it impossible by applying this idiom. Maybe the design that requires special behavior is wrong.

**So my question is, this idiom is really useful of any base class? Should I always apply it? What are the disadvantages of applying this idiom?**

Comment: I think this question is a bit of style/opinion nature.  I find NVI idiom to be *very* helpful for **large** projects, but a hindrance for **small** or **medium** sized projects.  NVI is a clean *separation of concerns* between the public-facing API and the polymorphic API for derived classes.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for the comment. Are there any downsides to dealing with when using this idiom if this is simply a difference in style? What's in the way for small and medium-sized projects?

Comment: For small/medium sized project, to me, it seems that it's more busy work than useful.  YMMV.